# Find out the conditional probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

Consider I have the following probabilities:

$$P(A|B) = 0.86 $$

$$ P(A|B^C) = 0.35 $$

$$ P(B) = 0.80 $$

$$ P(A) = 0.758$$

Is there necessary information given to calculate $P(B^C|A^C)$? If so please guide me how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Nope, am revising for a test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for the conditional probability is simply:
$$
P(B^c\mid A^c)=\frac{P(B^c\cap A^c)}{P(A^c)}.
$$
You can calculate the denominator based on your information, so we only need to treat the numerator. Using the formula above with $B^c$ and $A^c$ interchanged, you obtain
$$
P(B^c\cap A^c)=P(A^c\mid B^c)P(B^c).
$$
Now, try to see if you can find an expression of $P(A^c\mid B^c)$ in terms of $P(A\mid B^c)$.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. However way i look at it, even applying bayes theorm

I still need this P(B^c|A^c) to calculate this P(A^c∣B^c), which led me to the conclusion that something is missing in the q...

Comment: You don't need to use Bayes' theorem to find $P(A^c\mid B^c)$. Simply write out the expression and use the law of total probability.

Comment: Ok what ive got...

Complement of a conditional
'P(A^c|B) = 1 - P(A|B) = 0.14'

Law of total probability

Comment: Ok what ive got...

Complement of a conditional:
P(A^c|B) = 1 - P(A|B) = 0.14

Law of total probability:
P(A^c) = P(B) * P(A^c|B) + P(B^c) * P(A^c|B^c)
0.242 = 0.80 * 0.14 + 0.2 * P(A^c|B^c)
P(A^c|B^c) = 0.65

Hence
P(B^c∩A^c) = 0.65 * 0.2 = 0.13

Which is a wrong answer? So where did i go wrong? Sorry for trouble, i cant edit the comments to look nice

Comment: @kype: Why not use your first formula for $P(A^c\mid B^c)$? Then $P(A^c\mid B^c)=1-P(A\mid B^c)$ which you can compute.